# ASP.NET MVC3 razor problem with international characters in custom html helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I currently trying to convert a ASP.NET MVC2 application to ASP.NET MVC3 razor. I have a lot custom Html helper methods, which render html output, like the one below, which renders a button with some markup :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<input type='submit' id='")
            .Append(buttonId)
            .Append("' name='" )
            .Append(buttonId)
            .Append("' value='")
            .Append(buttonValue)
            .AppendLine("' class='myclass1 myclass2' />");
return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
```

When the buttonValue contains international characters like é or ë, the text of the button gets rendered wrong, I guess some kind of encoding occurs...

Eg. ë is changed to Ã«

I know, MVC3 uses some kind of templating system for its html helpers, but as I have a lot of my own helpers it would take to much time to get to know this and to change all my current custom helpers.

Comment: Apparently, default MVC3 Html helpers suffer from the same problem:
@Html.TextBox("test","Kopiëren")
will also output the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, apparently it had to do with the encoding of the cshtml files, which were generated with a small c# program which tries to convert webform syntax to razor syntax. When writing the resulting cshtml file, if forgot to specify the encoding parameter, which resulted in a different encoding of the cshtml file compared to the original aspx or ascx file. I solved it by changing

```
File.WriteAllText(filename,text)
```

to

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, text,Encoding.Default)
```